# Login form issue with spring security 2.0.7 and spring 2.5

Tags: spring-security

Hi i am trying to put a login page on my application.
My login.jsp is

```
    <form name='f' action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />"
        method='POST'>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='j_username' value=''>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type='password' name='j_password' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"
                    value="submit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'><input name="reset" type="reset" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Login controller

@Controller
public class LoginController {

```
 @RequestMapping("/user/login.do")
    public ModelAndView handleLoginForm(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String errParam = request.getParameter("error");
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("login");
        if(errParam != null) {
            mv.addObject("error", "Benutzer oder Kennwort unzul&auml;ssig");
        }
        return mv;
    }
```

}

spring secuirty xml

```
    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login"
            access="ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check"
            access="ROLE_USER" />
        <form-login login-page="/login"
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" default-target-url="/userPage.do"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error=1" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login"
            logout-url="/logout" />
    <!--    <intercept-url pattern="/user/userPage.do" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <form-login login-page="/user/login.do" default-target-url="/user/userPage.do"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />  -->
    </http>


   <authentication-provider>
                <user-service id="userDetailsService">
                        <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
                        <user name="username" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                        <user name="test" password="test" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                </user-service>
   </authentication-provider>

</beans:beans>
```

spring xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>


    <bean id="userFormValidator" class="com.validator.UserFormValidator"/>

    <bean id="userProxy"
        class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="target" ref="userManager" />
        <property name="interceptorNames">
            <list>
                <value>transactionInterceptor</value>
            </list>
        </property>
   </bean>

    <bean id="genderManager" class="com.service.impl.GenderManagerImpl">
    </bean>

    <bean id="userProxyBean" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="proxyInterfaces">
          <value>com.service.UserManager</value>
        </property> 
        <property name="target">
          <ref bean="userManager" />
        </property>
        <property name="interceptorNames">
          <list>
            <value>loggerAdviser</value>
          </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="genderProxyBean" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="proxyInterfaces">
          <value>com.service.GenderManager</value>
        </property> 
        <property name="target">
          <ref bean="genderManager" />
        </property>
        <property name="interceptorNames">
          <list>
            <value>loggerAdviser</value>
          </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="loggerAdviser"  class="org.springframework.aop.support.RegexpMethodPointcutAdvisor">
      <property name="advice">
         <ref bean="loggingInterceptor"/>
      </property>
      <property name="patterns">
         <value>.*</value>
      </property>
    </bean> 

    <bean id="loggingInterceptor"  class="com.log.LoggingInterceptor"/>

    <bean id="userDetailController" class="com.web.UserDetailController">
      <property name="userManager"><ref bean="userProxyBean"/></property>
    </bean>  

    <bean id="loginController" class="com.web.LoginController">

    </bean>  

    <bean id="userController" class="com.web.UserController">
      <property name="sessionForm"><value>true</value></property>        
      <property name="commandName"><value>userBean</value></property> 
      <property name="commandClass"><value>com.beans.UserBean</value></property>   
      <property name="validator"><ref bean="userFormValidator"/></property>
      <property name="formView"><value>userForm</value></property>
      <property name="successView"><value>userDetail.do</value></property>
      <property name="userManager"><ref bean="userProxyBean"/></property>
      <property name="genderManager"><ref bean="genderProxyBean"/></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
      <property name="urlMap">
         <map>
            <entry key="/user/userPage.do"><ref bean="userController"/></entry>
            <entry key="/user/userDetail.do"><ref bean="userDetailController"/></entry> 
            <entry key="/user/login.do"><ref bean="loginController"/></entry> 
         </map>
      </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"><value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView</value></property>
        <property name="prefix"><value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value></property>
        <property name="suffix"><value>.jsp</value></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>context</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <!-- Spring context loading ends-->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>user</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>user</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
       <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>uk.ltd.getahead.dwr.DWRServlet</servlet-class>
       <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>/spring</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/spring.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

   </web-app>
```

Now when ever i hit http://localhost:8080/springhibernate/user/login.do
it shows me login page but when click login  it always gives me error

The requested resource (/springhibernate/user/j_spring_security_check) is not available.
The page is redirected to http://localhost:8080/springhibernate/user/j_spring_security_check

Please help me to solve this issue and suggest me how this login feature can be implimented in my app i am stuck with it

Answer (score 1):

I have pretty much the same setup with a separate login form, but on login action the following method get's called:

(see edit)

Not too sure how it works but appearently it's neccessairy:
http://ocpsoft.com/java/jsf-java/spring-security-what-happens-after-you-log-in/

**EDIT:**

my form:

```
<h:form id="loginForm" prependId="false">
        <label for="j_username"><h:outputText value="Username:" /><br />
        </label>
        <h:inputText id="j_username" required="true">
        </h:inputText>

        <br />
        <br />
        <label for="j_password"><h:outputText value="Password:" /><br />
        </label>
        <h:inputSecret id="j_password" required="true">
        </h:inputSecret>

        <br />
        <br />
        <label for="_spring_security_remember_me"> <h:outputText
                value="Remember me" /> </label>
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="_spring_security_remember_me" />
        <br />

        <h:commandButton type="submit" id="login"
            action="#{loginBean.doLogin}" value="Login" />

    </h:form>
```

Login bean:

```
@SessionScope
public class LoginBean implements Serializable
{  
    private String j_username;        
    private String j_password;        
    private String _spring_security_remember_me;        

    public String getJ_username() {
        return j_username;
    }    
    public void setJ_username(String j_username) {
        this.j_username = j_username;
    }    
    public String getJ_password() {
        return j_password;
    }    
    public void setJ_password(String j_password) {
        this.j_password = j_password;
    }    
    public String get_spring_security_remember_me() {
        return _spring_security_remember_me;
    }    
    public void set_spring_security_remember_me(String _spring_security_remember_me) {
        this._spring_security_remember_me = _spring_security_remember_me;
    }       

    // This is the action method called when the user clicks the "login" button
    public String doLogin() throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ((ServletRequest) context.getRequest())
                 .getRequestDispatcher("/j_spring_security_check");

        dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest) context.getRequest(),
                (ServletResponse) context.getResponse());

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
        // It's OK to return null here because Faces is just going to exit.
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi pete you mean we need to include this method in login controller coz i am not using any login bean or login filter as your blog

Comment: Yeah, the controller is your login bean (it's a singleton bean) and has to call that method for some reason..

Comment: Pete i am not using JSF in my code so these context classes wont be part of it :(

Comment: Maybe you can get the context some other way? Also: did you try calling just `/j_spring_security_check` or `/springhibernate/j_spring_security_check` in your browser ? I had other issues implementing my form converning the correct URL. Might be you have to change the mapping..

Comment: @Arvind i have removed that part and using this now <http auto-config="true">
  <intercept-url pattern="/user/userPage.do" access="ROLE_USER" /> but still this is giving me the same problem 
  <form-login login-page="/user/login.do" default-target-url="/user/userPage.do"
   authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
  <logout logout-success-url="/logout" /> 
 </http>

Answer (score 0):

Here are my working configs for your reference . They seem to be quite the same . These are for Spring 3.0 . Haven't tried with 2.x but thought this may help you .

```
<!-- Spring-security -->

 <http auto-config="false" access-denied-page="/login.jsp?error=Access%20Denied">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp*" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/manager/**" access="${manager.roles}" />
    <form-login login-page="/login.jsp"
                default-target-url="/welcome.jsp" 
                always-use-default-target="true" 
                authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?error=true" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login.jsp"/>   
    <anonymous/>
  </http>    
  <authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
      <user-service>
              <user name="a" password="a" authorities="ROLE_MANAGER" />
          </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>


<!--Jsp -->

<form name="login" action="<c:url value="j_spring_security_check"/>" method="POST">
<table width="40%" border="4" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#E3DBB8">
  <tr><td bgcolor="#FFF4C3"><br>
   <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" frame="box">
    <tr>

        <td align="right" nowrap><font face="Tahoma" size="+1">User Name:</font></td>
        <td align="left" width="300"><input id="username" tabindex="1"
            type="text" name="j_username" maxlength="20" border="1" style="width: 150px"/ ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" nowrap><font face="Tahoma" size="+1">Password:</font></td>
        <td align="left"><input id="password" tabindex="2" type="password" name="j_password" maxlength="20" style="width: 150px"/></td>
    </tr>       
    <tr>
        <td align="right"><input type="submit" tabindex="3" name="login" value="  Login  " class="Button" /></td>
        <td align="left">
        <input type="reset" tabindex="3" name="reset" value="  Reset  " class="Button" />
        </td>
    </tr>

   </table><br>
  </td></tr>
</table>
</form >

 <!--Web.xml -->

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I have included authentication-provider directly as i read somewhere on blogs that manager is required for spring version 3.* not below that

Comment: Thanks Arvind i saw them these are fine with spring 3.0 and spring 2.8 is quite similar for it i think i am wrong some where on controller page and spring bean definition but what is the problem i am not getting :(

Comment: @viren one more thing  , spring security takes and processes call from the login page and redirects the error back to the login page . But you have a  @RequestMapping("/user/login.do") which maps the request to your controller . So instead of going to the failure page , it probable goes to the controller . Something's wrong here . Put a  RequestMapping for the userPage.do  instead of the login page and put a debugger/print stmt in the controller and check if it reaches there on successful login .

Comment: @Arvind i tried with these new methods as you suggested  @RequestMapping(value="/user/userPage.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String printWelcome(ModelMap model, Principal principal ) {
 
  String name = principal.getName();
  model.addAttribute("username", name);
  model.addAttribute("message", "Spring Security Custom Form example");
  return "userPage";
 
 }
 
 @RequestMapping(value="/user/login.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String login(ModelMap model) {
 
  return "login";
 
 } BUt still i am getting same issue

Comment: @Arvind can you show me how you guys have defined your login controller and how its mapping is done in config xml file

Comment: @viren - We use GWT here . Try the sample [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-example/)